# Access to dynamically created QML objects from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML object, which can create the same objects inside of it. The function addChildRect is called from C++. Each object is provided with its unique `id` and `objectName` (for each object they are the same). I want to get access to them from C++ using `QObject::findChild`, **but for dynamically created object this function always returns null pointer**. My suggestion is, that this function parses only objects, that were in QML initially. How can I get access to dynamically created objects from C++?

**Rect.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    color: "red"
    function addChildRect(id,x,y,width,height)
    {
        var component;
        component = Qt.createComponent("Rect.qml");
        component.createObject(this, {
                               id:id,
                               objectName:id,
                               x:x,
                               y:y,
                               width:width,
                               height:height});
    }
}
```

**C++ code:**

```
//find element
auto parentRectView = engine.rootObjects().first()->findChild<QObject*>(QString::number(id())); 


//create element
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(parentRectView,"addChildRect",
                          Q_ARG(QVariant,id()),
                          Q_ARG(QVariant,m_position.x()),
                          Q_ARG(QVariant,m_position.y()),
                          Q_ARG(QVariant,m_size.height()),
                          Q_ARG(QVariant,m_size.width()));
```

Comment: I guess you should set parent for  dynamically created objects to find if with `QObject::findChild`. Also, to avoid unnecessary actions you just can return pointer to created object from `addChildRect` to C++

Comment: @folibis thank you for your answer? did I understand you properly, that I should add `parent: this` in QML object construction code? 
Also could you please provide me simple example, how to return pointer from QML?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Trying to "find" objects created in QML is usually a bad idea and there are almost always better ways of achieving the actual goal.

For example creating multiple objects of the same type, each having its own associated C++ data set, is most likely a case for using a `Repeater` on the QML side and providing the data from C++ via a custom `QAbstractListModel` derived class.

Comment: @KevinKrammer I was facing a similar issue. Thanks for bringing up the Repeater, which is definitely the way to go since it can just have every size and each element can look different and can be in very different place through the delegate. Greetings to Graz btw. Awesome City! (I loved Schwalbennest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have following QML code (main.qml):

```
Window {
    width: 300
    height: 400
    visible: true
    id: window

    Component {
        id: testItem
        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "green"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

    function addItem(name)
    {
        var component = testItem.createObject(window.contentItem, {objectName: name});
        return component;
    }
}
```

Pay attention - as a parent I pass `Item`, in my case this is `Window.contentItem` - a hidden root item of `Window` since Window isn't `Item`.
I'm not javascript guru but I think `this` you use here is a pointer to the function, not to `Item`.

Ok, and here is a C++ code:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
QObject *item = dynamic_cast<QObject *>(engine.rootObjects().at(0));
QVariant retVal;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(item, "addItem", Qt::DirectConnection,
                           Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariant, retVal),
                           Q_ARG(QVariant, "test"));

qWarning() << retVal;
```

In my case the output will be something like

> QVariant(QObject*, QQuickRectangle(0x2c125490, name = "test"))

You just need to cast `QVariant` to `QQuickItem` or `QObject`.

As for finding the dynamically created objects you are right. For example the output of the following code:

```
QObject *rect = qvariant_cast<QObject*>(retVal);
qWarning() << rect;
QObject *myitem = item->findChild<QObject *>("test");
qWarning() << myitem;
```

will be:

```
QQuickRectangle(0x2c270d38, name = "test") 
QObject(0x0)
```

`findChild` returns null although `parent` of `rect` is set.
Maybe someone can explain this strange behavior.

Comment: Use `qobject_cast` for `QObject` and derived, it is better in several aspects, performance including.

Comment: @folibis `parent` in QML is the "parentItem", as in `QQuickItem::parentItem()` which is not necessarily the same as the QObject parent, as in `QObject::parent()`